# How to run an sql query inside a while loop

Tags: php

i have two db and need to fetch them in array and also count number of one row but when i put second query inside while loop it dose not work at all and when i but it outside loop then gave me just count of last apiary
my 1db:

```
apiary_id , apiary_name 
1              A
2              B
3              c
4              d
```

my 2db:

```
  hive_id, hive_number, apiary_id
    1              01         1
    2              02         2
    3              02         1
    4              04         2
    5              05         4
```

my php code:

```
<?php
include 'db/db_connect.php';
//Query to select apiary id and apiary name
$query = "SELECT apiary_id, apiary_name, FROM apiaries";
$result = array();
$apiaryArray = array();
$response = array();
//Prepare the query
if($stmt = $con->prepare($query)){
    $stmt->execute();
    //Bind the fetched data to $apiaryId and $apiaryName
    $stmt->bind_result($apiaryId,$apiaryName);
    //Fetch 1 row at a time 
    while($stmt->fetch()){

        //Populate the apiary array
        $apiaryArray["apiary_id"] = $apiaryId;
        $apiaryArray["apiary_name"] = $apiaryName;
        $count = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($con, "SELECT hive_id FROM hives WHERE hives.apiary_id".$apiaryId));
        $apiaryArray["hive_count"] = $count;
        $result[]=$apiaryArray;
    }
    $stmt->close();
    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["data"] = $result;
}else{
    //Some error while fetching data
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = mysqli_error($con);
}
//Display JSON response
echo json_encode($response);

?>
```

i need result like this:

```
   Apiary ID - Apiary Name - Count of Hives
    1              A               2
    2              B               2
    3              c               0
    4              d               1
```

i will be happy if somebody help me.

Comment: I see multiple problems with your code.  My advice would be to try to consolidate your logic down to a single query, which looks possible, at least at a quick glance.

Comment: the result will be in json array right?

Comment: -Nancy Mooree Yes

Comment: Tim Biegeleisen is it ok to help me lite??

Comment: Stay tight, am working on it

Comment: It has been answered. good luck

Comment: – Nancy Mooree, i think one query is not possible because i fetch apiary_Id in the while loop.

Comment: nobody want to help me ???

Comment: – Nancy Mooree did you find any way to fix it??

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo,

```
hives.apiary_id =1".$apiaryId
```

should be

```
hives.apiary_id =".$apiaryId
```

So the whole statement should be,

```
$count = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($con, "SELECT count(*) FROM hives WHERE hives.apiary_id =".$apiaryId));
```

Comment: thanks i fixed but the same problem. when i delete second query php it is work but when i write inside while loop it dos not work